# Posting a list of data in a single col in Kendogrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to do something like this in my grid... this is basically what i have so far:

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                        .Name("childgrid_#=ParentId#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.Object1Name).Title("Message Types").Width(200);
                            columns.Bound(p => 
                            foreach(Object2 obj2 in Object2Props)
                            {
                                obj.Object2Id
                                obj2.Object2Name
                            }
                            ).ClientTemplate("#=ParentId#");
                        })
....
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class Object1
    {
        public int Object1Id{ get; set; }
        public string Object1Desc { get; set; }

        public List<Object2> Object2Props{ get; set; }


    }

    public class Object2
    {
        public int Object2Id { get; set; }
        public string Object2Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Can this be done?  If so how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use server side `Template()`, something like this:

```
columns.Template(@<text>
    <table>
    @foreach(var i in item.Object2Props)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@i.Object2Id</td>
            <td>@i.Object2Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</text>);
```

or clientside template:

```
columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate("#=templateFunction(data)#");
```

where `templateFunction` is your javascript function that return constructed html and parameter `data` is dataItem for corresponding row:

```
<script>
function templateFunction(data)
{
    return ....;
}
</script>
```

Comment: columns.template is throwing an error saying ambiguous invocation... I'm assuming because of my columns.bound statement right above it.  I'm using the foreach code you provided (what I'd prefer to use)

Comment: Also this grid is a child grid. it's wrapped in <script> tags

Comment: @tshoemake modified server side template, but i am using only clientside templates in my projects